# React js setstate not working in nested axios post

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios, es6-promise

I am trying to access the res.data.id from a nested axios.post call and assign it to 'activeId' variable. I am calling the handleSaveAll() function on a button Click event. When the button is clicked, When I console the 'res.data.Id', its returning the value properly, but when I console the 'activeId', it's returning null, which means the 'res.data.id' cannot be assigned.
I just need to assign the value from 'res.data.id' to 'metricId' so that I can use it somewhere else in another function like save2() function.
Does anyone have a solution? Thanks in advance

```
const [activeId, setActiveId] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {}, [activeId]);

const save1 = () => {
      axios.get(api1, getDefaultHeaders())
        .then(() => {
          const data = {item1: item1,};

          axios.post(api2, data, getDefaultHeaders()).then((res) => {
            setActiveId(res.data.id);
            console.log(res.data.id); // result: e.g. 10
          });
      });
};

const save2 = () => {
  console.log(activeId); // result: null
};

const handleSaveAll = () => {
  save1();
  save2();

  console.log(activeId); // result: again its still null
};

return (
  <button type='submit' onClick={handleSaveAll}>Save</button>
);
```

Comment: `save2()` won't wait for `save1()` to resolve

Comment: setState function is asynchronous. It's not updated straight away. Also, your axios calls are promises, so it takes some time to resolve them. 

Put that console.log in your useEffect that you have, and you will see the value of activeId being updated

Comment: Actually If I put it in the useEffect, it wouldn't solve my problem because I need the value of 'activeId' in save2() function, i console it just to confirm that the value is assigned or not. How can I get value of 'res.data.id' from the save1() function and assign it to 'metricId' so that I can use this value inside the save2()?

Comment: so it will be better to understand if you show your complete code ( component )

Comment: It is almost the complete code @DeepKakkar

Comment: Why don't you call `save2()` in the `then` of `axios.post` in `save1()` and by passing a parameter to `save2`? That's how you deal with promises, you do something once it resolves, not before. Or as others have suggested, you'll have to use `async/await`.

Answer (score 1):

This part of code run sync

```
const handleSaveAll = () => {
  save1();
  save2();

  console.log(activeId); // result: again its still null
};
```

but there you run async

```
axios.get(api1, getDefaultHeaders())
        .then(() => {
```

You can refactor your code to async/await like this:

```
const save1 = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get(api1, getDefaultHeaders());
      const response2 = await axios.post(api2, { item1: response.data.item1 }, getDefaultHeaders());
      return response2.data.id;
};

const save2 = (activeId) => {
  console.log(activeId); // result: null
};

const handleSaveAll = async () => {
  const activeId = await save1();
  save2(activeId);
  setActiveId(activeId);
  console.log(activeId); // result: again its still null
};
```

or to chain of promises, like this:

```
const save2 = (activeId) => {
  console.log(activeId); // result: null
};

const save1 = () => {
  return axios.get(api1, getDefaultHeaders())
    .then(({ data }) => {
      const data = {item1: item1,};
      return axios.post(api2, {item1: data.item1}, getDefaultHeaders())
    })
    .then((res) => res.data.id);
};

const handleSaveAll = () => {
  save1()
    .then((res) => {
      setActiveId(res.data.id);
      console.log(res.data.id); // result: e.g. 10
      return res.data.id;
    })
    .then(save2);
};
```